# next.js and react . "MODULE _NOT_FOUND"

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, oauth-2.0, node-modules

hello guys I want to run my app and after the "npm run dev" command I see the "MODULE_NOT_FOUND" error can anyone help me fix it
my node version "v20.6.1"
my npm version "10.2.5"

"PS C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Ultimate Ecommerce Development with React & Next.js\udemy\nextecom> npm run dev

> nextecom@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

'Next.js\udemy\nextecom\node_modules.bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\next\dist\bin\next'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.6.1"

i try to add some path in the environment variables

Answer (score 0):

I feel this error popped up because of how you have named your directory. Make sure there is no space character in the directory name. Change the directory name from,
Ultimate Ecommerce Development with React & Next.js
To this: Ultimate_Ecommerce_Development_with_React_&_Nextjs. You can do this by changing the folder name in file explorer.
After making this change your directory path would look like this in your terminal.
`C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Ultimate_Ecommerce_Development_with_React_&_Nextjs\udemy\nextecom`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I changed it but it doesn't work. if you have any other ideas it would be helpful. thanks